ieugwasr: I have an access token but I am unable to download data from the ieugwasr API
I'm using the ieugwasr package, and whilst I was trying to rerun some analyses,
library("stringr", "tidyr", "data.table", "TwoSampleMR", "MendelianRandomization", 
        "tibble", "httr", "jsonlite", "remotes", "readxl", "dplyr", "vroom")

outcome <- extract_outcome_data(snps="rs251905", 
                                outcomes = 'ebi-a-GCST90018974',
                                proxies = F)

The following error occurred:

Extracting data for 1 SNP(s) from 1 GWAS(s)
Error in ieugwasr::associations(variants = snps, id = outcomes, proxies = proxies,  :
unused argument (access_token = access_token)

This is strange because I never had any problems with access tokens before when I used this package to access dataand its functions.
I then found my way to the link below and tried the steps in the tutorial.
https://mrcieu.github.io/ieugwasr/articles/guide.html#authentication
However, even after following the steps, I still could not call extract_outcome_data. This is puzzling because the two checkpoints in the tutorial returned the desired outcome:

To check that your token is being recognised, run ieugwasr::get_opengwas_jwt(). If it returns a long random string then you are authenticated.

get_opengwas_jwt() returned my access token. This means that I "am authenticated".

To check that your token is working, run user(). It will make a request to the API for your user information using your token. It should return a list with your user information. If it returns an error, then your token is not working.

user() also returned a list of my user information, meaning my token worked.
Would appreciate any advice and suggestions.

Please edit your question to include all code and libraries required to reproduce your issue. Thanks.

It turns out when all else fails, drastic measures were required, i.e. uninstalling and reinstalling the TwoSampleMR and ieugwasr packages!
